# The Church, and denominations. — I'm confused. — "Denominations" are not in any unison. I thought Christ wanted us to be all ONE

Tags: marriage, bride

Christ is The Groom, the Church (that HE established in fulfillment of the old order) is the Bride. In the last 500 years there's been a substantial influx of "denominations." Why? Doesn't that make our Lord & Savior a polygamist? In Matt 16:18 He says "And so I say to you, you are Peter, and upon this rock I will build my Church, and the gates of the hell shall not prevail against it."
Notice He said "Church" (singular) — NOT churches (plural)

Comment: The church is spiritual not an earthly sect and denomination.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stack exchange.

You seem to have 3 questions here:

1. The unity of the church
2. The rock of the church
3. Are multiple denominations multiple brides?

Q1: The church is to be united, though that unity must be in the truth. Phil 1:27 teaches that we are to be of one mind. Jesus claimed to be "the way, the truth, and the life", and that "no man commeth unto the Father, but by me" (Jn 14:6).

Yes, God designed His church to be united, but that unity must be in the truth. In an effort to hold to the truth, various denominations have split off. Paul warns against this in 1 Cor 1, speaking of those splitting after different leaders. We should be united on Christ. Some however do split after different leaders, causing different denominations.

Proverbs warns that "only by pride commeth contention", so we must be careful of approaching issues through pride, but rather focus on the truth.

Q2: This is an excellent example of causes of division in  Christ's church. In the passage you reference, Jesus asks His disciples who people say they are. After Peter acknowledges (by the Holy Spirit) that Jesus is the Christ, Jesus replies that upon this rock, being that truth which the Holy Ghost revealed to Peter, Christ will build His church.

Some denominations teach that the rock mentioned is Peter, being that his name means rock. However, Christ is the long-prophesied Corner Stone and the Rock of Stumbling. Peter cannot be the foundation of the church, but rather Jesus Christ Himself. If you read the complete passage again, you may see it this way. The rock upon which Christ builds the church is the fact that Jesus is "the Christ, the Son of the Living God", not Peter. To be saved, you must believe that Jesus is the Christ, not that Peter is the head of the Church.

I, who believe that Jesus is the Rock of the Church, and that the church as His bride must seek to please Him and abide in the TRUTH, cannot in good conscience unite with those who teach that Peter, or those they call his appointed heirs, are the pillar of the church. For this cause, I must separate from those who teach a doctrine contrary to what I read in the Bible.

> Mat 16:13-20 KJV - 13 When Jesus came into the coasts of Caesarea
> Philippi, he asked his disciples, saying, Whom do men say that I the
> Son of man am? 14 And they said, Some [say that thou art] John the
> Baptist: some, Elias; and others, Jeremias, or one of the prophets. 15
> He saith unto them, But whom say ye that I am? 16 And Simon Peter
> answered and said, Thou art the Christ, the Son of the living God. 17
> And Jesus answered and said unto him, Blessed art thou, Simon Barjona:
> for flesh and blood hath not revealed [it] unto thee, but my Father
> which is in heaven. 18 And I say also unto thee, That thou art Peter,
> and upon this rock I will build my church; and the gates of hell shall
> not prevail against it. 19 And I will give unto thee the keys of the
> kingdom of heaven: and whatsoever thou shalt bind on earth shall be
> bound in heaven: and whatsoever thou shalt loose on earth shall be
> loosed in heaven. 20 Then charged he his disciples that they should
> tell no man that he was Jesus the Christ.

Q3: As the church is rightly composed of saints (see below), Christ has but one bride, The Church.

> Rom 1:7 KJV - 7 To all that be in Rome, beloved of God, called [to be]
> saints: Grace to you and peace from God our Father, and the Lord Jesus
> Christ.
> Rom 12:13 KJV - 13 Distributing to the necessity of saints;
> given to hospitality.

> Rom 15:25 KJV - 25 But now I go unto Jerusalem
> to minister unto the saints.

> Rom 16:15 KJV - 15 Salute Philologus, and
> Julia, Nereus, and his sister, and Olympas, and all the saints which
> are with them.

> 1Co 1:2 KJV - 2 Unto the church of God which is at
> Corinth, to them that are sanctified in Christ Jesus, called [to be]
> saints, with all that in every place call upon the name of Jesus
> Christ our Lord, both theirs and ours:

> 1Co 6:1-2 KJV - 1 Dare any of
> you, having a matter against another, go to law before the unjust, and
> not before the saints? 2 Do ye not know that the saints shall judge
> the world? and if the world shall be judged by you, are ye unworthy to
> judge the smallest matters?

That church is composed of all who have made their garments white in His blood, that is, to have been born again (Jn 3) by accepting Him for Who He claimed to be, and put their trust in Him (Rom 10). There are likely saved in all denominations, and it is these that compose the church. In the NT, there are a plethora of references to church, and by the context, you must determine which refer to local churches (ex Rev 2-3), and which to "The Church" (Mt 16:17).

Comment: PART ONE of 6
Thank you so much tmct for your splendid and in-depth answer, and the time you took.
I can only hope I can contribute something constructive (and riveting?) to the discussion.

I have to respectfully disagree with you on #2 (The rock of the church)

Of course Christ is the cornerstone, but Simon-Peter is indeed the rock. In John 1:42 Andrew brought him (Simon-Peter) to Jesus, who looked at him and said, "You are Simon son of John. You will be called Cephas" (which is translated as Peter).

Comment: PART TWO of ➔ make it 7
Christ changed Simon's name, which is very significant. God changed other people's names also: 
➖Abram "high father," to “Abraham,”  "father of all nations" (Genesis 17:5).  
➖“Sarai,” “my princess,” to “Sarah,” “mother of nations” (Genesis 17:15). 
➖Jacob "supplanter," to “Israel,” “having power with God”

Comment: PART THREE of 7
➖And Simon to Peter. Another point about "This Rock" is from the grammatical point of view, the phrase “this rock” must relate back to the closest noun. Peter’s profession of faith (“You are the Christ, the Son of the living God”) is two verses earlier, while his name, a proper noun, is in the immediately preceding clause.

Why does God change people's names? The Bible doesn't really say, but the common view is that it was to let them know they were destined for a new mission in life.

Comment: PART FOUR of 7
The overarching context in the relevant versus in Matthew 16 is the KINGSHIP of Christ. —  Christ is a king, that's the main reason for Matthew chapter one, to prove His Davidic lineage and that He's next in line for the throne. Christ (the King) promised Simon-Peter the "Keys of the kingdom of Heaven" (the "keys" are a symbol of authority) and the power to bind and loose.  

This episode was foreshadowed in Isaiah 22 with Shebna and Eliakim

Isaiah 22:15-22 = 15) Thus says the Lord, the GOD of hosts: Up, go to that official, Shebna, master of the palace,

Comment: PART FIVE of 7
16) “What have you here? Whom have you here, that you have hewn for yourself a tomb here, Hewing a tomb on high, carving a resting place in the rock?”  17) The LORD shall hurl you down headlong, mortal man! He shall grip you firmly,  18) And roll you up and toss you like a ball into a broad land. There you will die, there with the chariots you glory in, you disgrace to your master’s house!  19) I will thrust you from your office and pull you down from your station.  20) On that day I will summon my servant Eliakim, son of Hilkiah;

Comment: PART SIX of 7
21) I will clothe him with your robe, gird him with your sash, confer on him your authority. He shall be a holy father to the inhabitants of Jerusalem, and to the house of Judah.
➔ 22) I will place the key of the House of David on his shoulder; what he opens, no one will shut, what he shuts, no one will open.
(Of note, the Davidic King's prime minister had successors, in this case Eliakim was the successor to Shebna.)

Comment: PART SEVEN of — make it 10 (sorry)
There's a similarity with Matthew 16.
When we understand that Christ is the true “son of David” who came to restore the prophetic Kingdom of David, we understand that Christ in Matthew 16, like the King of Israel, was establishing a “prime minister” among his ministers—the apostles—in the Kingdom. Isaiah 22:15-22 gives us insight into the ministry of the “prime minister” in ancient Israel.

Comment: PART EIGHT of 9
In Revelation 1:18, Jesus declares, “I have the keys of Death and Hades.” He then quotes this very text from Isaiah in Revelation 3:7 = "And to the angel of the church in Philadelphia write: “The words of the holy one, the true one, who has the key of David, who opens and no one shall shut, who shuts and no one opens.”" — In Matt 16:19 Christ tells Simon-Peter  “I will give you the keys to the kingdom of heaven. 14 Whatever you bind on earth shall be bound in heaven; and whatever you loose on earth shall be loosed in heaven."“

Comment: PART NINE of 9
No Christian would deny Jesus is the King who possesses the keys. But as King he gives the keys to his prime minister - Peter. ➖➖ In Matthew chapter 18 Christ grants the authority to bind and loose to the rest the apostles what was previously given to Peter alone. However, the "Keys of the Kingdom of Heaven" aren't mentioned there. Those are only for Peter — and passed down to his successors, like Eliakim's "Keys" were held by his predecessors and successors. 
Thanks again for your response, and your welcoming me to Stack Exchange.